# How to improve the performance of multiple left joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have a trouble performance when I made multiples left joins in a query.
There are 10 left joins in my query, if I show the information of 5 left joins works so fast but if I show information more of 5 left joins (6,7,8,etc.) takes 30 seconds to show the information. Example:

This is my original query that takes 32 seconds

```
SELECT `users`.id,
       `directions`.`name`      AS `subgrupo_1`,
       `positions`.`name`       AS `subgrupo_2`,
       `sites`.`name`           AS `subgrupo_3`,
       `subgrupo_fours`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_4`,
       `subgrupo_fives`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_5`,
       `subgrupo_sixes`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_6`,
       `subgrupo_sevens`.`name` AS `subgrupo_7`,
       `subgrupo_eights`.`name` AS `subgrupo_8`,
       `subgrupo_nines`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_9`
       ....
       ....
```

If I comment some information like this, takes 0.18 seconds

```
SELECT `users`.id,
       `directions`.`name`      AS `subgrupo_1`,
       `positions`.`name`       AS `subgrupo_2`,
       `sites`.`name`           AS `subgrupo_3`,
       `subgrupo_fours`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_4`,
       `subgrupo_fives`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_5`,
       -- `subgrupo_sixes`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_6`,
       -- `subgrupo_sevens`.`name` AS `subgrupo_7`,
       -- `subgrupo_eights`.`name` AS `subgrupo_8`,
       -- `subgrupo_nines`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_9`
       ....
       ....
```

If I uncomment one information like this, takes 32 - 34 seconds

```
SELECT `users`.id,
       `directions`.`name`      AS `subgrupo_1`,
       `positions`.`name`       AS `subgrupo_2`,
       `sites`.`name`           AS `subgrupo_3`,
       `subgrupo_fours`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_4`,
       `subgrupo_fives`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_5`,
       `subgrupo_sixes`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_6`,
       -- `subgrupo_sevens`.`name` AS `subgrupo_7`,
       -- `subgrupo_eights`.`name` AS `subgrupo_8`,
       -- `subgrupo_nines`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_9`
       ....
       ....
```

If I comment one information and uncomment other information like this, takes 0.18 seconds

```
SELECT `users`.id,
       `directions`.`name`      AS `subgrupo_1`,
       `positions`.`name`       AS `subgrupo_2`,
       `sites`.`name`           AS `subgrupo_3`,
       -- `subgrupo_fours`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_4`,
       `subgrupo_fives`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_5`,
       `subgrupo_sixes`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_6`,
       -- `subgrupo_sevens`.`name` AS `subgrupo_7`,
       -- `subgrupo_eights`.`name` AS `subgrupo_8`,
       -- `subgrupo_nines`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_9`
       ....
       ....
```

I saw that If I get 5 information of my left joins works well but if I get 6 o more information of my left joins takes to time, no matter which information I get always take too long time if I get more than 6 left joins.
Its crazy!!

*** EDITED
I put the original query

```
SELECT `users`.id,
       `directions`.`name`      AS `subgrupo_1`,
       `positions`.`name`       AS `subgrupo_2`,
       `sites`.`name`           AS `subgrupo_3`,
       `subgrupo_fours`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_4`,
       `subgrupo_fives`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_5`,
       `subgrupo_sixes`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_6`,
       `subgrupo_sevens`.`name` AS `subgrupo_7`,
       `subgrupo_eights`.`name` AS `subgrupo_8`,
       `subgrupo_nines`.`name`  AS `subgrupo_9`
FROM   `users`
       LEFT JOIN `directions`
              ON `users`.`direction_id` = `directions`.`id`
                 AND `directions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `positions`
              ON `users`.`position_id` = `positions`.`id`
                 AND `positions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `sites`
              ON `users`.`site_id` = `sites`.`id`
                 AND `sites`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `subgrupo_fours`
              ON `users`.`subgrupo_4` = `subgrupo_fours`.`id`
                 AND `subgrupo_fours`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `subgrupo_fives`
              ON `users`.`subgrupo_5` = `subgrupo_fives`.`id`
                 AND `subgrupo_fives`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `subgrupo_sixes`
              ON `users`.`subgrupo_6` = `subgrupo_sixes`.`id`
                 AND `subgrupo_sixes`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `subgrupo_sevens`
              ON `users`.`subgrupo_7` = `subgrupo_sevens`.`id`
                 AND `subgrupo_sevens`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `subgrupo_eights`
              ON `users`.`subgrupo_8` = `subgrupo_eights`.`id`
                 AND `subgrupo_eights`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       LEFT JOIN `subgrupo_nines`
              ON `users`.`subgrupo_9` = `subgrupo_nines`.`id`
                 AND `subgrupo_nines`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
WHERE  `users`.`user_profile_id` = 4
       AND users.id IN (SELECT patient_vaccinations.user_id
                        FROM   `patient_vaccinations`
                        WHERE  `patient_vaccinations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
       AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
GROUP  BY `users`.`id`
LIMIT  100 offset 0
```

Comment: Removing columns from the `SELECT` list shouldn't make much difference. Are you also removing the corresponding tables from the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Every join multiplies the amount of work that has to be done.

Comment: Are you joining on fields that are not indexed in both tables?  That can cause delays

Comment: You should probably post your entire query to see HOW your joins are so declared.  Edit your existing post and put the entire query in.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: The rest of the query (JOINs, ONs, WHERE, GROUP BY, etc) is quite important to this Question.  In addition that, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Hello! guys thanks for your messages. I put the original query.
@Barmar No, I don't remove LEFT JOINS just the SELECT´s

Comment: @Daves Yes, the joining fields are indexed in both tables

Comment: Do you see any difference in the `EXPLAIN` output when you remove columns from the `SELECT` list? Maybe an optimization is possible if you're not referencing any columns from a table that's being `LEFT JOIN`ed. This might show up in the `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 0):

You only provided the `select` clause, which usually does not contribute significantly to the performance problems your query may have. The `select` clause may also be slow in some cases, if it has to fill a lot of memory, but you can find out whether the `select` clause is your culprit by removing all columns and leaving the joins as they were:

```
select 1
from <your ten joined tables>;
```

If this is slow, which is probably the case, then you need to focus on the `from` and `join` clauses.

We know that some of the last five tables are making it slow. So, you will need to find out which `table` is the culprit. Try it with six tables (without the last 4) and then with seven tables and so on. If it was quick for n tables and is slow for n + 1 tables, then the (n + 1)th `table` is the culprit. Try indexing the fields you are using for your `join`. Also, it may be the case that there are too many records in the `table` which represents the culprit.

So, as a general rule, you will need to find what the culprit is, ignoring any further complications for the time being and try and optimize the culprit. If you are successful and the query is still slow, then find the next culprit and so on.

If you conclude that this is impossible, then structural or strategic changes might be needed, depending on your schema and project.